# generating dynamic click event in code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, sharepoint, web-parts

I am generating dynamic html in my visual webpart in sharepoint.

```
 htmlString = "<a href='#'  onclick='updateAge(" + itemId + ")'>";
```

I want to write click event in code behind in c# for the click event. The click event should accept parameter.

How to achieve this? I can easily do this javascript by writing function but not sure how i do in code behind.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already resolved how to send the link html and you just need to send the Javascript, you could use [`Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string script = @"function updateAge(itemId) { 
    // here write your logic!
    alert(itemId);
    someOtherFunction();
}

function someOtherFunction() {
    // your logic for this other function
}";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "myscript", script, true);
```

Comment: Where to write code inside updateAge method? Would really appreciate if there is some example

Comment: Remember i want to write everything in code behind and not in javascript

Comment: so i write my logic in that string. What if i call another function from inside that function. Where do i write then that function?

Comment: in the same string, above or below the other one. See my edit

Comment: so i keep my html string i wrote in question as it is and write this code 
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "myscript", script, true);

in page_load event   ??

Comment: HTML has nothing to do with `RegisterStartupScript`, it's only for Javascript. You'll need to send HTML using some other mechanism

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79573/discussion-between-happy-and-claudio-redi).